# How to setResult() for a TabActivity which contains activity for tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

My TabActivity contains two tabs which calls two two different activities . I want to setResult() for the TabActivity when either one of the child finishes.

Is there any method to find out when my activity inside tab finishes ?

Thank you
-Eby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another way

```
`   @Override
    public void finishFromChild(Activity child)
    {
        setResult(REFRESH);
        super.finishFromChild(child);
    }
`
```

finsihFromChild will let us know when the child activity is finishing!!
@pentium10 thank you very much for your suggestion..

Answer (score 3):

Ok i've got an even easier method to pass the result:

in your child activity do this

```
Intent list = this.getIntent();
list.setAction(Integer.toString(RESULT_CODE_TO_PASS));
finish();
```

and then in the parent do this:

```
@Override 
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) { 

        Intent test = child.getIntent();
        setResult(new Integer(test.getAction()));
        super.finishFromChild(child); 
        }
```

Comment: actually to clean up the code just do this in your child activity this.getIntent().setAction(Integer.toString(RESULT_CODE_TO_PASS));

Answer (score 1):

You need to issue a Broadcast from your child activity(when finished) and implement the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) on the class you want to catch the broadcast. You can use the extras to transfer data from one activity to another.